# How to tell the debugger not to stop on exceptions?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I have an odd behavior inconsistency between two of my machines, running the same environment (Same OS, same IDE version, same flutter version, same app code).

My app scans the entire local network looking for a certain device. To do so, I send a GET on every IP (192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.254). If nothing is at the end, I get a socket exception "no route to host". This is normal behavior, the GET is ran in a try/catch, and the exception is just printed for debugging purposes.

On my Laptop, when I press "Debug", the app is loaded to my smartphone, and runs. Exceptions produce a red output in the terminal. Nothing else, the app just keeps running.

On my Desktop, when I press "Debug", the app is loaded to my smartphone, and runs. Both the debugger and the terminal are opened, and the execution is paused at every exception.

I'm very confused, and to be honest, I don't know which of my machines is producing the expected behavior.

Where in the IDE can I find the setting triggering this behavior? (Stop at exception vs just output them and continue running).

Answer (score 0):

On Android Studio, while running a Flutter project in debug mode, you can disable the exceptions from stopping the execution by tapping into the "View Breakpoints...":

[image]

And then, disabling the exceptions (or any breakpoint) there:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can change it at `DevTools->Debugger` with changing to `Dont stop on exceptions`.

Comment: I cannot find it on Bumblebee (